# how to put two divs positioned horizontally if there is not enough space in parent div

Tags: html, css, position

I have a parent div which can expand and shrink vertically. Inside there are two children divs. I would like to position the children depending on the height of the parent div:

- vertically: if parent div's height allows both children to be positioned vertically.

  - parent ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |-child1 ------------|
    |----------------------|
    |-child2 ---------------------------------|
    |-------------------------------------------|
    |
    |
    |-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
- horizontally: if parent div's height has not enough room for the children to be set vertically.

  - parent ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |-child1 --------------||-child2 ---------------------------------|
    |------------------------||-------------------------------------------|
    |-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

I have tried setting the parent's position relative and children's position absolute with one of them top = 0 and the other bottom = 0, but they overlap when parent div shrinks.

HTML code:

```
<div id="screen_header">
 <div id="sh_header">Header text</div>
 <div id="sh_subheader">Explanation text</div>
</div>
```

CSS code:

```
#screen_header{
 position: relative;
}
#sh_header{
 font-size: 24px;
 padding: 10px;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0px;
}
#sh_subheader{
 padding-left: 10px;
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0px;
}
```

Any ideas?

Thank you,

Comment: Did you try float???ie. give the two divs `float:left`

Comment: if you can post a fiddle too,it will be much easier for us to help you out..

Comment: Yes please paste html and css into jsfiddle.net

Comment: is this what you want???http://jsfiddle.net/yyL6aq8c/

Comment: Using float: left I always have the children aligned horizontally. But I would like it to happen only if the height of the parent does not allow to have them aligned vertically.

Answer (score 0):

If you make the child divs widths relative to the parent's width they should shrink with the parent div. e.g. HTML:

```
<div id="parent">
<div id="child1"></div>
<div id="child2"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#parent {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#child1{
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
}

#child2{
    float: right;
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
}
```

This is just concept code and will need modifying to suit your needs.

Comment: The fact is that the parent expands and shrinks VERTICALLY, not horizontally.

Comment: Try setting a fixed height in pixels and the width as a percentage, that should stop it.

Comment: You need JS to calculate the height of both items and the parent and then act accordingly.